# Teradata-How to search for a column in view definition-

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

How do I search if a column is used in view definition either as a source or destination I tried to search in requesttext in dbc.tables but after 12500 characters there is a truncation happening.I cant change the dbc.tables definition.Please tell me a way to find if a column is used in a view definition

Comment: When you say "used" do you mean projected in the `SELECT` list or just referenced somewhere in the view like a `JOIN` condition?

Comment: Don't use legacy DBC.Tables deprecated since Teradata 12.0; use DBC.TablesV. And if RequestTxtOverflow is set in TablesV you need to use DBC.TableTextV instead (which may have multiple rows of text, in which case it could be split in the middle of a word).

Comment: Keep in mind that (sadly enough...) this is not much of a substitute for proper documentation.   You'll probably get lots of false positives.  Identical column names will probably exist in multiple tables. If you're looking for a given column name, you won't be able to tell without actually reading the DDL if the column was used in the select, join clause, where clause, etc.